# Use bounding box with raster package

Tags: polygon, raster

I'm trying to use the raster package to get a partial view of Portugal, using a bounding box

`library(raster)`

`pt <- getData('GADM', country='Portugal', level=1)`

I'm not used to work with this kind of data, so I'm actually lost.

All I know is that I need to crop this information using this bounding box:

`bbx[1,1] = -9.290005`

`bbx[2,1] = 38.612098`

`bbx[1,2] = -8.969858`

`bbx[2,2] = 38.836554`

Can anyone help? I really need to get the information from raster package using the getData function.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

```
library(raster)
pt <- getData('GADM', country='Portugal', level=1)
```

If you just want to plot a small area, you can do

```
plot(pt, xlim=c(-9.290005, -8.969858), ylim=c(38.612098, 38.836554))
```

Or you can create a SpatExtent and use crop to cut out the area of interest

```
e <- extent(-9.290005, -8.969858, 38.612098, 38.836554)
a <- crop(pt, e)
plot(a)
```